# java script to concatenate a comma separated list with single codes'

Tags: javascript, jsp

how can i concatenate my array input with single codes in my JSP.
Input will be:

```
abc,efg,hij
```

and i want make it :

```
'''abc'',''efg'',''hij'''.
```

There is an additional code at the start and end also.

Comment: *"...in my JSP"* That's Java, not JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

In javascript,

`var str = abc,efg,hij`

to include all individual elements into single quotes, do

`var strModified = "'"+str.replace(/,/g, "','")+"'"`

output will be

`'abc','efg','hij'`